# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended mystery error

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble getting this query to run. I keep getting an ORA-00933 error. As far as I can tell, it should "end" just fine... there's nothing extremely fancy going on here. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you!

```
SELECT /*+ use_hash(r, sub) */
to_char(r.request_day,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS request_day,
r.marketplace_id,
CASE
    WHEN (r.client_name = 'CreturnRefundEngine' AND REGEXP_LIKE(r.client_unique_request_id,'^RMA[-][0-9]*[-][0-9]*$')) THEN 'RefundAtFirstScan'
    ELSE 'OTHER'
END early_refund_type, 
sum(r.reversal_id) as refund_qty
FROM
d_reversal_item_units r
JOIN
D_MP_ASINS sub 
ON
sub.asin = r.asin and
sub.region_id = r.region_id and
sub.marketplace_id = r.marketplace_id
WHERE
sub.subcategory_code in ('42400105','42400305','34900105') and
sub.marketplace_id in ('1','4') and
sub.region_id in ('1', '2')
r.region_id in ('1', '2') and
r.marketplace_id in ('1','4') and
r.request_day between to_date('20120101','YYYYMMDD')-110 and to_date('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')+1 AND
(
    (r.client_name = 'ConcessionsService' AND (r.client_unique_request_id LIKE '%RFNDcreturns%' OR r.client_reference_id LIKE 'CReturns-RR-%'))
    OR
    (r.client_name = 'CreturnRefundEngine' AND r.CLIENT_REFERENCE_ID_TYPE = 'RefundRequestReferenceID' AND REGEXP_LIKE(r.client_unique_request_id,'^[0-9]+-.*-[0-9]+$'))
    OR
    (r.client_name = 'creturnrefundengine' and regexp_like(r.client_unique_request_id,'^rma[-][0-9]*[-][0-9]*$'))
)
group by
to_char(r.request_day,'YYYY-MM-DD'),
r.marketplace_id,
case
    when (r.client_name = 'CreturnRefundEngine' and REGEXP_LIKE(r.client_unique_request_id,'^RMA[-][0-9]*[-][0-9]*$')) then 'RefundAtFirstScan'
    else 'OTHER'
end
```

Comment: please please please format your code as per the guidelines to help us look at your code more easily . Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that! Still getting the hang of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sub.region_id in ('1', '2')

you are missing AND after this so this should be

```
sub.region_id in ('1', '2') AND
```

Comment: Thank you Satya! I guess I've been staring at this for far too long.